# How to simulate plot to illustrate findings of a game-theoretic model in R?

Tags: r, simulation

I developed a game theoretic model. I have the following result:

[image]

What I want to do is write an R function to simulate how the parameter *s* changes in terms of *q*, fixing the other parameters at the following values:

```
gamma = 1/4
alpha = 1
theta = 1/4
L = 0.5
```

What I envision is a plot with *s* on the y-axis and *q* on the x-axis. Both range from 0 to 1. I have written the following, but I am unsure of how to go from here:

```
# Define the function
partial_derivative_pi <- function(q, L, theta, gamma, alpha, s) {
  term1 <- q * (1 - L) / ((-L + theta * (1 - gamma)^2) * (-L + s * gamma^2 - theta^2 * (1 - gamma))) * gamma^alpha * (gamma^2 * s - theta^2 * (1 - gamma) * (2 - gamma))
  term2 <- q * (1 - L) / ((-L + theta * (1 - gamma)^2) * (-L + s * gamma^2 - theta^2 * (1 - gamma))^2) * gamma^2 * ((-L + theta^2 * (1 - gamma)^2) * (gamma^alpha - s * gamma^alpha - gamma^2 * theta^2))
  term3 <- q / (-L + s * gamma^2 - theta^2 * (1 - gamma)) * gamma^2 * (theta^2 + gamma^alpha - theta^2 * gamma^2)
  term4 <- -q / ((-L + s * gamma^2 - theta^2 * (1 - gamma))^2) * gamma^2 * (1 - L) * (gamma^alpha - theta^2 * gamma^2)
  
  return(term1 + term2 + term3 + term4)
}

# Set fixed parameter values
L <- 0.5
theta <- 1/4
gamma <- 1/4
alpha <- 1
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to move forward? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Map` to apply your function to each point in a grid of values of `s` and `q`, then plot the result using `geom_tile` in `ggplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- expand.grid(q = seq(0, 1, length = 200), s = seq(0, 1, length = 200))

dat$value <- unlist(
  Map(function(q, s) partial_derivative_pi(q, L, theta, gamma, alpha, s),
      q = dat$q, s = dat$s))

ggplot(dat, aes(q, s, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_distiller(expression(over(delta*pi, delta*s)), 
                       palette = 'Spectral') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

To show lines at various fixed values of the output variable, we can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)

ggplot(dat, aes(q, s)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_textcontour(aes(z = value, label = after_stat(level)), color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_distiller(expression(italic(over(delta*pi, delta*s))), 
                       palette = 'Spectral') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]+

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to get a single line visualizing how s varies as a function of q?

Comment: No, @w5698 `s` does not vary as a function of `q` unless you have a fixed value of dpi/ds. Every color on this plot shows how the value of s varies as a function of q for each given value of dpi/ds.

Comment: To clarify, by fixed value of dpi/ds, do you mean solving for s and thus obtaining a value s^*?

Comment: I mean that if you fix the other parameters, then both q and s are free to vary between 0 and 1, and any two values of q and s will give a value for dpi/ds. It's a bit like saying "I have a function z = x + y. How can I draw a graph of how y varies against x as a single line?". You can't, of course, unless z is fixed. If z is 3, then 3 = x + y so y = 3 - x, which you can draw as a line. If you have three variables without fixed values, then the solution is a 2D surface in 3D space, not a 1D line on a 2D plane. 3 variables needs a surface (or representation of a surface) to show it graphically

Comment: I have added some lines for various fixed values of `dpi/ds` @w5698

Comment: Perhaps a better way of putting it is that there are an infinite number of s values for each q, unless you set the further constraint of fixing dpi/ds as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I really appreciate it. I guess what I want to visualize is how the level of a policy (s) chosen by an actor varies across levels of q. In the context of my theoretical model, dpi/ds is the optimal level of s for the actor. I want to see how s changes across levels of q. I'm not sure if I'm explaining that correctly. Or perhaps that is what you've done and I'm just not understanding it.

Comment: @w5698 your partial derivative function doesn't allow you to see how s changes across q, because both s and q are free to vary. The function allows s and q to vary however you like, without constraint. As a result, there _is_ no single value for `s` for a given `q` implied by your function. For any of the variables s, q and dpi/ds, you need two of them to work out the value of the third. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Gotcha, now this makes sense. I really appreciate the explanation and help!